# Detecting change completion on form input

Tags: jquery

I have a fetish for building online calculators without the big 'Calculate' button. i.e., the calculations occur on change event without users clicking on the calculate button. Unfortunately, many users just enter data and scroll down to see the results without tabbing out or clicking elsewhere on the screen. This behaviour doesn't trigger the change event and so the results don't update.

Here are some scenarios where I consider user input is complete:

1. User enters data and tabs out (change)
2. User enters data and moves the mouse out from the text box (keypress/input followed by mouseleave)
3. User tabs into the input field, enters data and moves the mouse a certain distance elsewhere. i.e., mouse isn't on the input field at any time.

Implementing #1 & #2 should be easy. I am trying to see how best to implement #3 using jQuery. Are there any jQuery plugins available to help me with all the above or just #3?

Or, should I just abandon all this and put a big calculate button?

Comment: if you are certain that the user will always have to scroll to the result div you can check when it is scrolled in and calculate the results

Comment: just do the calculation on change , on focus , on keyup and maybe detect if someone presses enter .. and you will be all done

Comment: Why not just use `keyup` for the change event and trigger that when the page is loaded?

Comment: The mouse may not always move towards the results. The user may just move the cursor to the side.

Comment: I initially used keypress event combined with a few seconds delay (using bindWithDelay.js) to determine that the user input is complete. But my users are old / slow and it caused results getting updated with incomplete input. Less delay = incomplete input, more delay = bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an simple calculator that updates on every input change. (Didn't add the checks that the value is an int and so.)

```
$('#num1, #num2').bind('keyup', function() {
    if($('#num1').val() == '' || $('#num2').val() == '') {
        $('h1 b').html(0);
    } else {
         $('h1 b').html( parseInt($('#num1').val()) + parseInt($('#num2').val()) );
    }
}).trigger('keyup');
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/DV4HT/1/)

Comment: I cannot use keyup event for reasons mentioned above.

Comment: This does not answer the question.